# Ulimit change the max number of open files?

Tags: linux, ssh, ulimit

I needed to increase the maximum number of open files for a program run and I used `ulimit -n new_max_number`. I tried it several times and it works some of the times, and gives error of `-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted`.

Actually at first I thought it was about they set the limit for 4096 which is the number I used in my first try. However, later I realized sth strange. When I connect to server via ssh, the first change using ulimit -n number works regardless of a limit. However, any later change using ulimit -n number, where the new number is greater than the current one does not work. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the hard limit.
As an unprivileged user you can only ever lower hard limits, never raise them.

Use `-S` to set only the soft limit.
Soft limits can be raised up to the value of the current hard limit.

Note that shells differ as to which limits they set, soft or hard, when neither the `-H` nor the `-S` option is used.
You are clearly using one of the ones that sets the hard limit in this circumstance.